# Why does my teacher say "the simple harmonic oscillator passes through the amplitude four times in one cycle"?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I asked him to explain it. But he simply told that where the sinusoidal graph the x axis counts as two times. I don't get why.

I thought the answer should be three.

[image]

Comment: Pick any other point except the min/max of the wave and recount.

Comment: That would be 2

Comment: I think by "amplitude" they mean "absolute value," so you get 2*2=4.

Comment: How why not 3??

Comment: |sin(pi/4)|=|sin(3pi/4)|=|sin(5pi)/4|=|sin(7pi/4)|=1/sqrt(2)

Comment: @Andrew, can you explain why those are where the amplitudes are? I didn't give you any numbers. And I thought you use cosine to find position.

Comment: A problem here is the word "amplitude".  The usual definition is *the maximum extension* in which case the answer is two.  If instead is meant *some value of the extension other than full extension or zero*, the answer is 4.  Very badly worded.

Comment: I took the wording to mean "the amplitude (absolute value) of a sine wave equals some constant A four times over the course of one cycle," which is true so long as 0<A<1. I gave the example A=1/sqrt(2) because it is simple. I agree the wording is bad.

Comment: Ask your teacher what he/she thinks you've learned from this statement. Imho nothing. The most important property of the harmonic oscillator is that the period is independent of the amplitude(=the maximum deviation).

Comment: I'm on the same page with @Praan . There is not much value in this question and it just confuses the student. While there is value in understanding what **amplitude** means "..passing through the amplitude .." is just a nonsensical way to use the term.

Answer (score 4):

Since the amplitude is the distance of farthest travel from the center, perhaps this is what your teacher meant:

1. Center to +A
2. +A to center
3. Center to -A
4. -A to center.

This constitutes a single oscillation and the mass travels a distance of 4A.

Comment: In other words, the oscillator passes through a distance equal to 4 amplitudes. This may be the original statement.

Comment: Wow, could be!   We haven't seen the original statement, but the one that has come to us is **extremely** badly worded!

Comment: This. But it is still a nasty phrase. I'd go with *"travels a distance of 4 $A$"* or something similar if I wanted to express that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a value less than A, say, A/2.

The amplitude may be thought of as the distance from 0 (or, as already pointed out, simply the absolute value).

With this in mind, how many times does the function in your graph reach a distance of A/2 from the zero-line? If you wish, you can plot the absolute value of the function and reach the same answer.